# accessing a class field from a delegate

Tags: c#

So I have a simple User Class:

```
public class User
{
    public string id, name, email, image;
    public User (IFBGraphUser user)
    {
        id = user.GetId ();
        name = user.GetName ();
        GetEmail ();
    }


    private void GetEmail()
    {
        FBRequestConnection.StartWithGraphPath("/me", null, "GET", delegate(FBRequestConnection connection, NSObject result, NSError error) {
            var me = (FBGraphObject)result;
            this.email = me["email"].ToString();
        });
    }
}
```

But I need to get the users email from Facebook. My Facebook request has a delegate and when I try to **assign the email field inside the delegate**, the email field remains null. How can I go about getting the email into the email field from the delegate?

Its not a problem with the facebook result, ive tried `this.email = "test";` and it was still `null` when I went to access it.

Comment: Does `StartWithGraphPath` method calls the delegate you pass as parameter?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes it does.

Comment: Can you post `StartWithGraphPath` method code? and also put a breakpoint inside the delegate and debug it to see whether it is called.?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I cant post the code because its from the facebook sdk and I only have the dll. I have debugged and still cannot figure it out.

Comment: That's fine. So answer is simple. add a breakpoint and see if that delegate executes or not. If not investigate why.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the delegate is executing. I put a console print in it to test. The assignment of the email field isnt working for some reason.

Comment: How sure are you? may be `me["email"].ToString();` returns empty?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel as I said in my question ive also tried `this.email = "test";` instead with no luck.

Comment: the delegate is not being invoked i think..

Comment: i think you should call this InvokeOnMainThread method while setting the email or call the invoke the delegate in another way ...

Answer (score 0):

In this Code i am setting a class level field's value and accessing it outside of delegate so this might help you, see the below given code:-

```
public delegate void delgJournalBaseModified(string a);
public class User
{
    public string id, name, email, image;
    public User(string uid,string uName)
    {
        id = uid;
        name = uName;
        Console.WriteLine(this.name);
        Console.WriteLine(this.email);
        GetEmail();
    }


    private void GetEmail()
    {
        set(delegate(string d)
        {
            this.email = d;
        }); 
    }

    private void set(delgJournalBaseModified delgJournalBaseModified)
    {
        delgJournalBaseModified.Invoke("value is set");
        Console.WriteLine(this.email);

    } 
}
```

and call like this in  main method or anywhere you like..

```
User a1 = new User("123", "dev");
Console.WriteLine(a1.email);
```

now if you will the console "value is set" is being print twice.

Thanks
Devendra